# Convert accents to HTML, but ignore tags

Tags: php, html, encoding

The code below converts text for characters with accents. But it also converts the HTML tags which I would like to leave intact. How can I only convert accented characters and leave all other special characters intact? Thanks.

```
$temp = file_get_contents("file.html");
echo htmlentities($temp,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlspecialchars_decode()` will only encode/decode `&`, `<`, `>`, `'` and `"`; you could thus use the latter to convert their entities back to their HTML special characters:

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($temp, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Comment: This also works when a on a page both encoded and plain entities are used (eg: both `<` and `&lt;`). The risk on converting and instantly back-converting is that, in some cases, parts of the original text might be unintentionally lost. In this case, `<` will turn into `&lt;` and then **all occurences of `&lt;`** are converted to `<` back again, including all occurences of `&lt;` in the original text.

However, this is not the case, because the entity delimiter `&` itself is also converted! So you don't have to worry about unintended conversion of text. Sounds pretty obvious, but I just remind.

Answer (score 1):

A but of a hack, but you can apply `htmlentities()` like you already do it first, and then reverse it for the standard xml characters (`<`,`>`,`&`,`"`,`'`) using [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). This will restore the tags.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work OK

```
if (!function_exists('make_accents')):
function make_accents($string)
{
    //$string = "<p>Angoulême</p>";
    $trans = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    //$encoded = "&lt;p&gt;Angoul&ecirc;me&lt;/p&gt;";
    $encoded = strtr($string, $trans);
    //Next two lines put back the < & > tags
        $noHTML = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $encoded);
    $encoded = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $noHTML);
    return $encoded;
}
endif;
```

Comment: In my case, the get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES); strtr($string, $trans); was enough to do the direct output of my content.